# Change user password functionality -> password is saved, but I wont log in

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I'm writing a function to enable the users to change their password.

```
        public function change_password() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            debug($this->request->data);
            $tmpUsr = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('user_id'))));
            debug($tmpUsr);
            $tmpUsr['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['Change']['Confirmation']);
            if ($this->User->save($tmpUsr)) {
                debug("saved new password: " . $tmpUsr['User']['password']); // * after this debug is fired, the hash looks ok *
            } 
            else {
                debug("password was not saved");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**

The saved password looks hashed, but I tried it and it looks like the values saved arent the correct hash.

In the database the saved hashed string is not correct altough after debugging it where I commented it looks ok..

Any ideas where could be a problem?

Im using the login functionality from cake tutorial (2.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and it is just silly:

1. In the model there is a function beforeSave() where the hashing happens.
2. So the hashing happened twice (first time in the function change_password()) and then in beforeSave..

My mistake, sorry to take your time..

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$this->Auth->password($this->request->data['Change']['Confirmation']);
```

instead.

From the [API](http://api.cakephp.org/class/auth-component#method-AuthComponentpassword) docs "This method is intended as a convenience wrapper for `Security::hash()`"

Comment: `$this->request->data['Change']['Confirmation']` is `Confirmation` supposed to be capitalized?

Comment: If so, let's have a look at your `debug` output before and after the hash.

Comment: I found the answer and it is just silly:

1. In the model there is a function beforeSave() where the hashing happens.
2. So the hashing happened twice (first time in the function change_password()) and then in beforeSave..

My mistake, sorry to take your time..